# I need to link text from a Word 2010 text control field inside of Word to open a link

Tags: microsoft-word

Example would be,

Plain Text Content Control->Value

2345 Value entered.

So when I click on the CommandButton1 I open the link,
Shell "explorer.exe  http://www.google.com/2345"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a CommandButton I assume a solution using VBA and not just plain fields is wanted. In this case you can use the following code to get the text of a given Content Control and use that to build up the link that is used when the button is pressed.

```
Dim text
text = ActiveDocument.ContentControls(3).Range.Text
```